# what is the fix for "Could not resolve host" in R

Tags: r

When i try to locate the html file from a folder in my C drive location, I am getting the error as

```
getURL("The R-help January 2009 Archive by date.html",set.verifypeer=FALSE)

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: The R-help January 2009 Archive by date.html"
```

The R-help January 2009 Archive by date.html - is the name of the html file

Comment: Where is `getURL` coming from? If it's RCurl, the first argument should be a URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes here.  First, you are simply referring to the file by the filename alone, and R cannot determine where to actually find it.  If the file be located directly under the `C:` drive, then you should be referring to it as:

```
C:/The R-help January 2009 Archive by date.html
```

Second, if you want to tell `getURL()` to use a *file*, then you will have to use the `file://` protocol.  Try this call:

```
result <- getURL("file:///C:/The R-help January 2009 Archive by date.html",
                 set.verifypeer=FALSE)
```

Comment: by giving the above command i am getting the error as
Couldn't open file C:/The R-help January 2009 Archive by date.html

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?  Can you open this file in R from the File menu?

Comment: I am using windows10.. Rstudio

Comment: The code I gave you worked on my RStudio on Windows with an HTML file whose name had spaces in it.

Comment: it worked Tim.. thankyou..
btw i am new to R.. could you please provide any guidance in getting good at it.

Comment: Best way to get proficient at R is to just use it.  Stack Overflow is a great resource if you have specific questions.